# How to confirm that data has been written to chain?

Tags: ethers.js, evm, polygon, consensus

Using this toy solidity example:

```
contract ... {
    ...
    uint256 public value = 1;
    function setValue(uint256 x) public {
        value = x;
    }
}
```

Using `ethers`, if I call the above function to set value, the value is not immediately reflected in the read path:

```
console.log("initial value = ", await contract.value());
console.log("setting value to 10");
await (await contract.connect(signers[0]).setValue(10));
console.log("value after setting = ", await contract.value());
```

It gives:

```
initial value =  1n
setting value to 10
value after setting =  1n
```

The value will be reflected if a delayed is inserted:

```
initial value =  1n
setting value to 10
sleep for 4 secs
value after setting =  10n
```

This was done on polygon mumbai using the same node. I guess this means that:

- On the same node, data writes are not immediately reflected on the data reads because the latter needs to wait for consensus

The question is, how can I be sure that some data has reached consensus and is reflected in the read path, before I can perform the next step? Shall I keep polling a view function, wait for an event, wait for a few blocks so that consensus happens with high probability, or there is a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wait an appropriate number of blocks before calling the view function.

For instance:

```
const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, signer);
const tx = await contract.setValue(33);
// wait for the transaction to be mined
const receipt = await tx.wait(12);
```

When a transaction is **sent**, it is not immediately **confirmed**. The more blocks that are mined (committed to the blockchain) after your transaction is committed to a block, the greater the chance your transaction is done and irreversible. In Ethereum, it is usually 12 blocks. You can get more info about it here: https://developers.circle.com/developer/docs/confirmations

Not that, the return value is inaccessible during a write operation. Other techniques (such as events) are required if this value is required.

UPDATED

In general, if we need to perform a list of operation, each depending on the previous one, what are some best practices to implement it on evm?.

You can implement a callback and perform next action based on the execution. You can also emit an event and get the value from the smart contract, if needed.

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({from: '0x123...', data: '0x432...'})
.once('transactionHash', function(hash){ ... })
.once('receipt', function(receipt){ ... })
.on('confirmation', function(confNumber, receipt){ ... })
.on('error', function(error){ ... })
.then(function(receipt){
    // will be fired once the receipt is mined
});
```

Comment: Got it, but is there a way to know for sure that the state has reflected on the node I'm using? Like if I'm using an Alchemy node, I want to be notified when the write has been reflected on this specific Alchemy node. Can I emit an event in the txn and listen to it?    In general, if we need to perform a list of operation, each depending on the previous one, what are some best practices to implement it on evm?

Comment: You can use a callback to check that. I'm curious why do you want to check on just one node?